# Obtener registros que no esten en otra tabla

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla de productos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y una tabla de registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer una consulta a la tabla de productos en sql para que me retorne solo los productos que no se encuentran insertados en la table de registros.

algo así:

```
select * from productos where idProducto <> 6 and idProducto <> 2 and idProducto <> 4
```

pero necesito hacer de forma automática.

Este es el resultado que necesitaría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza el operador [`NOT IN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
 select * from productos where id NOT IN(select idProducto FROM registros)
```

Este te retornara los productos que no esten en la tabla `registros`.

Comment: Gracias, Me ayudó bastante

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes lograr de esta forma:

- Vincula ambas tablas a través de un `LEFT JOIN` para que en un primer momento te traiga tanto los productos que tienen relación con al menos un renglón en registros como aquellos que no
- Posterior filtramos los datos trayendo solo aquellos productos que no aparecen en registros indicando un filtro donde la llave foránea `idProducto` en la tabla registro sea igual a NULL

---

```
SELECT productos.idProducto, 
       productos.nombre
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN registros ON productos.idProducto = registros.idProducto
WHERE registros.idProducto IS NULL;
```